# Prove $\prod\limits_{\mathrm{cyc}}(2-x^2+x) \le 4 +x+y+z+xyz$ for $x^2+y^2+z^2=3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, symmetric-polynomials

> Let $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=3$. Prove that
> $$ (2-x^2+x)(2-y^2+y)(2-z^2+z) \leqslant 4 +x+y+z+xyz.$$

**Observations**

1. At first, I think this inequality is easy. I applied AM-GM to the term $(2-x^2+x) \text{ }$,$(2-y^2+y) \text{ }$,$(2-z^2+z) \text{ }$ then try to rewrite the new inequality in term of $u=x+y+z \text{ }$,$w=xyz \text{ }$,$\text{ } v=xy+yz+zx$.  Then I realized that the term $2-x^2+x$ can be negative. So the AM-GM approach fail.
2. I then try to homogenize the inequality, and hope that after expand every thing. I can obtain some obvious inequality. Well, I fail to homogenize it.
3. I try to assume $x\leqslant y \leqslant z$ and come up with some estimations but I get stuck.

I appreciate if anyone can attempt to solve it.

Comment: Not sure it helps, but using $2+x-x^2=(x+1)(2-x)$ creates opportunities to use AM-GM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hint:

$3(x^2+y^2+z^2) \ge (x+y+z)^2 \implies 3\ge x+y+z \ge -3,|xyz|^3 \le \sqrt{\dfrac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{3}}=1 \implies -1 \le xyz \le 1 \implies RHS \ge 0$

In Case LHS $<0$, the inequality is trivial true.

so you only need to consider LHS$ \ge 0$

there is two cases:

case 1: $2-x^2+x,2-y^2+y,2-z^2+z$  all positive. so you can use what you want.(but it is not easy also)

case2: two of them negtive, suppose $x<-1,y<-1$, then let $a=-x>1,b=-y>1,2<a+b \le \sqrt{2(3-z^2)} ,ab>1,|z|<1$

then RHS$ > f(z)>$LHS,try to find $f(z)$

another approach is expand LHS and replace with $uvw$ at both sides, then you will have to prove $f(w) \ge 0 \implies \Delta \le 0$, with $u^2-2v=3,|v|\le 3,|u|\le 3$, you should be able to get  $\Delta \le 0$